# cin causes an exception throw when using xtensor

Tags: c++, arrays, exception, cin, xtensor

I am trying to write a program using xtensor and it was working fine until I tried to use cin:

```
auto w=5;
cout << "Enter the 'n' for an nxn matrix: ";
//cin >> w;
cout << w;
if (!cin) { cout << "FAIL"; return 0; }
xarray<double> t;
t = nxn_array(4);
return 0;
```

With function definition:

```
xarray<double> nxn_array(unsigned int n) //shows original array being used
{
    auto show = empty<double>({ n,n });
    int c = 1; //lattic site index
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            show(i, j) = c;
            ++c;
        }
    }
    cout << show;
    return show;
};
```

It works fine if I comment out the `cin >> w`. But when I include it I get `Exception thrown at 0x004FF284 in File_Name.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x004FF284.` in the `xstorage.hpp` file. It also works fine if I comment out `cout << show;` but leave in `cin >> w`.

I'm not sure why this is. `w` isn't used at all. I think the exception is thrown at the `cout << show` part whenever `cin >> w` in included.

Comment: `cin >> w;` is not problem by itself. It is exposing some other bug that is not exposed when `w` is five.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. I recommend using a debugger to help you narrow down the problem and, if that doesn't  trigger a head-shake and bug fix, back up the code and start removing noise. Use [mcve] for inspiration. If you get stuck, add the reduced code to the question.